# How to get end_time and its value in groovy?

Tags: json, groovy

How to get end_time and its value in groovy, I'm trying but not getting an output.
I want to use the key and the value of the end_time.

```
   "values": [
                    {
                        "value": {},
                        "end_time": "2021-03-15T07:00:00+0000"
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: Show us what you tried so we can help you

Comment: @ou_ryperd end_time = value[0].end_time this I have tried, but I want the key (end_time) in a varaible and its value also in a variable

Comment: Could you please ask the question about the problem you are actually facing - your comment answers your own question and hints, that there is actually more to it than just that.

Comment: I want the the key (end_time) and its value in separate variables and I'm unable to get it

Comment: `def end_time='end_time'; def val = values[0][end_time]`

Comment: @RahulGour next time you ask a question, please provide a [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

The following code:

```
import groovy.json.*

def data = '''\
{
"values": [
            {
              "value": {},
              "end_time": "2021-03-15T07:00:00+0000"
            }
          ]
}'''


def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)
def endTimes = json.values.collect { it.end_time }

def firstEndTime = endTimes.first()

println "${endTimes} ${endTimes.getClass()}"
println "${firstEndTime} ${firstEndTime.getClass()}"
```

extracts first all the `end_time` values and then the first one of them. When executed, this prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy                                                                                          1 ↵
[2021-03-15T07:00:00+0000] class java.util.ArrayList
2021-03-15T07:00:00+0000 class java.lang.String
```